# Sending Email as HTML not showing context

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to set a logic so that when a user submits a design, a notification email is sent with the details of the post like Name, Title, Profile etc.

I am reached to the part where the email is sent but it is completely blank and empty except that when I typed random text it appeared but anything related to the name of user of post details it is not showing.

Here is the model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is the veiws.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'design']
    template_name = "post_form.html"
    success_url = "/score/"
    success_message = "Your Design has been submitted for Review"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.designer = self.request.user
        template = render_to_string("new_design_submitted.html", {'first_name': self.request.user.first_name,
                                                                  'last_name': self.request.user.last_name,
                                                                  'post': Post})

        msg = EmailMessage('New Design Submitted', template, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [self.request.user.email])
        msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
        msg.fail_silently = False
        msg.send()
        # End of the email send
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here is the email template

```
Hi {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}      <--------------- Only `Hi` appears 


        <div class='content_container' style="padding-top: 30px;position:relative;top:50px">
            <div class="dcard">
                    <div class="dcard_header">
                        <div class="profile_image" >
                            <img class="profile_image" src={{ post.designer.profile.image.url }}>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post_info">
                            <a style="margin-right: 3px"class="post_name" href="">{{ post.designer }}</a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="post_image">
                            <embed src="{{ object.design.url }}" alt=""></embed>
                    </div>
                    <p class="mb-2 ml-2">{{post.title}}</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the user has first and last name filled in? I mean `'post': Post` that isn't gonna work (class name, not Post instance), so if the logged in user has empty name fields, you don't see anything.

Comment: @Melvyn yes fixed the issue of the names but for the `{{post.title}}` is not showing

Comment: @Melvyn why `'post': Post` is not going to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Django Model is a class (Post). A class is a blueprint of a thing (`thing = Post()`). A thing is an instance of a class, created using the blueprint.

In a Django CreateView, the thing is obtained from calling [`form.save()`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid) and put on `self.object`.

Put this together:

```py
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.designer = self.request.user
        response = super().form_valid(form=form)
        template = render_to_string(
            "new_design_submitted.html",
            {
                 'first_name': self.request.user.first_name,
                 'last_name': self.request.user.last_name,
                 'post': self.object
            }
        )

        msg = EmailMessage('New Design Submitted', template, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [self.request.user.email])
        msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
        msg.fail_silently = False
        msg.send()
        # End of the email send
        return response
```